# Plotting Kernel Ridge Regression results in weird lines

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to run kernel Ridge regression on a simple artificial dataset. When I run the code, I get two plots. The first is for Linear Regression fit, which looks normal. however, the kernel one is very erratic. Is this expected behavior, or am I not calling the functions properly?

The first `plt.show()`:
[image]

The second `plt.show()`:
[image]

```py
from sklearn.kernel_ridge import KernelRidge
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


w = 5
x = np.random.randn(10, 1)
x_to_draw_line = np.random.randn(1000, 1)
y = w * x

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(x, y)
lr_preds = lr.predict(x_to_draw_line)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x_to_draw_line, lr_preds, color="C1")
plt.scatter(x, y, color="C0")
plt.show()


krr = KernelRidge(kernel="polynomial")
krr.fit(x, y)
krr_preds = krr.predict(x_to_draw_line)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x_to_draw_line, krr_preds, color="C1")
plt.scatter(x, y, color="C0")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Try sorting the `x_to_draw_line` when you create it: `x_to_draw_line = np.random.randn(1000, 1).sort()`

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler This answer worked (with some modifications to make numpy happy) - do you mind writing it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line plot appears jumbled because matplotlib draws a connecting line between each pair of points in the order they appear in the input array.

The solution is to sort the array of randomly generated x-values for which to generate and draw predictions:

```
x_to_draw_line = np.random.randn(1000, 1).sort()
```